# Compositing a swarm of insects on video footage

Tags: animation, particles, compositing-nodes, video, tracking

I'm trying to make a series of shots for a video where there are swarms of insects crawling on my hand and face like this bit from the Dalí/Buñuel film Un Chien Andalou where ants are crawling on the hand.

Ideas on the best way to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mention "composite", so ....

you could use the alpha-over composite node where your ants (represented here by small cubes, but if in motion you'd want a video of the bugs moving) appears on top of your rendering (could also be a video of your moving hand):

[image]
[image]

It would look as awful as one of those cheap 1950's movies or as laughable as the spider crawling up James Bond's arm in Dr No:

[image]

If you want realism, you'd have to do some modeling in blender and then perhaps some form of Particle System rendered as objects that are modeled as crawling ants -- might look better.

Comment: That sounds great. I do not want realism. The James Bond reference is exactly the direction I'm going in. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent -- okay, but I'll roll my eyes with your video, exactly as I do every time when I see this scene in the Bond movie, LOL ;)